# CFQ Understanding `cfq_cfq_cfqq_slice_new(cfqq)`

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

```
 static inline bool cfq_slice_used(struct cfq_queue *cfqq)
 {
         if (cfq_cfqq_slice_new(cfqq))
                 return false;

         if (time_before(jiffies, cfqq->slice_end))
                 return false;

         return true;
 }
```

I am looking at this code which is a complete fairness queue, which I found on http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/cfq-iosched.c#L4570

There is this line of code  `if (cfq_cfqq_slice_new(cfqq))` which to me looks like a function call where I just pass a cfqq struct. However, that function  `cfq_cfqq_slice_new` is not really declared, or I don't understand how it is declared when doing `crtl+f`

The search results yield:

```
WARN_ON(cfq_cfqq_slice_new(cfqq));
Other if statements checking the same thing, calling the same function.
```

So does anyone know what this code does or how it looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cfq_cfqq_slice_new(`) is defined through a macro.

On line 441 you'll see

```
CFQ_CFQQ_FNS(slice_new);
```

Which invokes:

```
#define CFQ_CFQQ_FNS(name)                                              \
static inline void cfq_mark_cfqq_##name(struct cfq_queue *cfqq)         \
{                                                                       \
        (cfqq)->flags |= (1 << CFQ_CFQQ_FLAG_##name);                   \
}                                                                       \
static inline void cfq_clear_cfqq_##name(struct cfq_queue *cfqq)        \
{                                                                       \
        (cfqq)->flags &= ~(1 << CFQ_CFQQ_FLAG_##name);                  \
}                                                                       \
static inline int cfq_cfqq_##name(const struct cfq_queue *cfqq)         \
{                                                                       \
        return ((cfqq)->flags & (1 << CFQ_CFQQ_FLAG_##name)) != 0;      \
}
```

resulting in:

```
static inline void cfq_mark_cfqq_slice_new(struct cfq_queue *cfqq) 
{                                                                  
        (cfqq)->flags |= (1 << CFQ_CFQQ_FLAG_slice_new);           
}                                                                  
static inline void cfq_clear_cfqq_slice_new(struct cfq_queue *cfqq)
{                                                                  
        (cfqq)->flags &= ~(1 << CFQ_CFQQ_FLAG_slice_new);             
}                                                                  
static inline int cfq_cfqq_slice_new(const struct cfq_queue *cfqq) 
{                                                                  
        return ((cfqq)->flags & (1 << CFQ_CFQQ_FLAG_slice_new)) != 0; 
}
```

A bit earlier in the code is a `enum` which declares:

```
CFQ_CFQQ_FLAG_slice_new,        /* no requests dispatched in slice */
```

So `cfq_cfqq_slice_new()` just returns whether or not the `CFQ_CFQQ_FLAG_slice_new` is set in the `struct cfq_queue.flags` member.